# PHP mySQL Issue

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by

I'm suddenly getting the following error when doing a fairly routine query: 
`Warning</b>:  mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource`

Here's my code:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM ImageGalleryPhotos ORDER BY ImageOrder";
$result = mysql_query($query);

/* create one master array of the records */
$imagesArray = array();

// here is the line where I'm getting the error I listed up top:
if(mysql_num_rows($result)) {      
    while($image = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $imagesArray[] = array('image'=>$image);
    }
}

echo json_encode($imagesArray); 

// And here I'm getting error # 2 (see below):
mysql_free_result($result);

?>
```

Error #2 is: `<b>Warning</b>:  mysql_free_result(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource`

The strange thing is that everything works just fine when I do the search without the "ORDER BY" business, like this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM ImageGalleryPhotos";
```

Comment: If you output `mysql_error()` after running the query, it'll tell you exactly what the issue is. You're assuming that your query has worked, and not doing any error checking at all.

Comment: Why don't you have `or die (mysql_error())` at the end of your `mysql_query()` line, so you'll see the error message?

Comment: Sounds like there's an error in your `ORDER BY`. Are you really sure you have an `ImageOrder` column in your table?

Comment: You are assuming your SQL query has succeeded.  Do not do this.  You should check to make sure it did.  `if($result === FALSE){ die(mysql_error()); }`

Comment: Sorry guys, I suppose I should mention that I'm not a PHP dev at all, I'm an Objective-C/iOS dev, and I've been given the task to do this work cause we're short-handed. I've cobbled together some PHP code from tuts online and so far so good - but I've hit the wall. Anyway, I'll try this `die(mysql_error())` bit and see what I get...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this first:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM ImageGalleryPhotos ORDER BY ImageOrder";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

It looks like you are having an error in your query.

Comment: Some of the values in my `ImageOrder` column were `NULL`, which I suppose is never a good thing. So that may have had something to do with it.  Otherwise, I did copy-paste your 2 lines of code so I could use the `or die(mysql_error())` bit and I'm suddenly not getting any errors - so I'm all good now. (Perhaps I also had some 'junk' characters in my code?) Either way, thank you :-)